# Generalized Reduced Gradient (GRG2) Algorithm in R

Tags: r, optimization

Does anyone know which R package has the implementation of Generalized Reduced Gradient (GRG2) Algorithm ? thanks

Comment: `library("sos"); findFn("{generalized reduced gradient}"); findFn("GRG2")` suggests you may be out of luck.  (Googling GRG2 suggests that the main implementation of this algorithm is in Excel's Solver.) Rather than asking "is this algorithm available?", you might ask "How can I solve the following problem?"

Comment: This was a good question, but 2 years old and no firm answer.  Has anyone created a GRG or GRG2 in function R?  I ask because I also have a situation where Excel's solver (relying on some kind of GRG) is fast and accurate on a problem that doesn't work very well with several optim() methods.

Comment: It's still actual. I didn't find any java implementation which I expected exists.

Answer (score 5):

Since @BenBolker has done the initial footwork in finding what sort of functionality you were hoping to replicate I'm posting a follow-up that might be useful. A recent exchange on Rhelp ended with a quote that was nominated for the R `fortunes` package, although it is not clear to me whether it was accepted:

```
"The idea that the Excel solver "has a good reputation for being fast
and accurate" does not withstand an examination  of the Excel solver's
ability to solve the StRD nls test problems. ...
Excel solver does have the virtue that it will always produce an
answer, albeit one with zero accurate digits."

"I am unaware of R being applied to the StRD, but I did apply S+ to the 
StRD and, with analytic derivatives, it performed flawlessly."

From:   Bruce McCullough <bdmccullough@drexel.edu>
Date:   February 20, 2013 7:58:24 AM PST
```

Here is a link to the self-cited work documenting the failures of the Excel Solver (which we now know is powered by some version of the GRG2 algorithm) by McCullough:
[www.pages.drexel.edu/~bdm25/chap8.pdf](http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~bdm25/chap8.pdf)  and the link to the NIST website for the testing problems are here: http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/strd/nls/nls_info.shtml and http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/strd/nls/nls_main.shtml

The negative comment (brought to my attention by a downvote) from @jwg prompted me to redo the search suggested by Bolker. Still no hits for `findFn( "GRG2")`. I can report several hits for "GRG" none of them apparently to a solver, and was amused that one of them has the catchy expansion to "General Random Guessing model". That seemed particularly amusing when the thrust of my arguably non-answer was that choosing to use Excel's solver left one genuinely uncertain about the accuracy of the solution. I am unrepentant about posting an "answer" that does not deliver exactly what was requested, but instead warns users who might not be religiously committed to the Microsoft way in this statistical/mathematical arena. The lack of any effort on the part of the distributed R developers to provide a drop-in-replacement for the Excel solver is something to ponder seriously.

Comment: The link for testing problems is dead. Is there a way you could find it again?

Comment: You should work on your googling skills. First hits for a search on: "NIST StRD nls test problem"

Comment: gov sites are often terrible with their data, I assumed it would have been relocated. I also thought it would be better that your answer provide a real link, and didn't want to edit in possibly relocated content. Thank you for the update.

Comment: This is not really a helpful answer. The fact that the Excel solver performs particularly badly on some class of problems, does not help someone who wants to solve some class of problems for which it does perform well, and wants to do so in R.

Comment: The author of the `optimix` package did not adopt the GRG2 algorithm as one of his options. It is _helpful_ to say that 1) smart people are not lining up to replicate Excel's choice and 2) to warn them why, and 3) and most on point here, to say there is no R package with that algorithm implemented. I just searched again: `sos::findFn("GRG2") #
found 0 matches)`

Answer (score 3):

Some relavant insights come from [this post to R-help](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-August/037218.html) by a reputable statistical scientist :

> The code in Excel is actually called GRG2 (the 2 does matter). Unlike
>   any of the methods for optim(), it can handle nonlinear inequality
>   constraints and does not need a feasible initial solution.
>
> There's a blurb about it in the NEOS optimisation guide:
>   http://www-fp.mcs.anl.gov/otc/Guide/SoftwareGuide/Blurbs/grg2.html
>
> Judging from this blurb, it will be similar to L-BFGS-B for problems
>   with no constraints or box constraints.
>     -thomas
>
> Thomas Lumley         Assoc. Professor, Biostatistics tlumley at
>   u.washington.edu  University of Washington, Seattle

So under some conditions it may be suitable to use `optim` like this in place of the Excel solver:

```
optim(pars, 
      OptPars, 
      ... ,
      method = "L-BFGS-B")
```

Note that the NEOS optimisation guide is now here: http://neos-guide.org/content/optimization-guide and GRG2 is mentioned on this page: http://neos-guide.org/content/reduced-gradient-methods It lists BFGS, CONOPT and several others as related algorithms. The article describes these as 'projected augmented Lagrangian algorithm.' According to the [Optimization CTV](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html), these algorithms can be found in nloptr, alabama and Rsolnp.

I've had good matches (to six sig figs) between the Excel solver and R using the `optimx` package, but YMMV.