# Recursive optim() function in R causes errors

Tags: r, optimization, r-portfolioanalytics

I am trying to use the `optim()` function in R to minimize a value with matrix operations. In this case, I am trying to minimize the volatility of a group of stocks whose individual returns covary with each other. The objective function being minimized is `calculate_portfolio_variance`.

```
library(quantmod)

filter_and_sort_symbols <- function(symbols)
{
  # Name: filter_and_sort_symbols
  # Purpose: Convert to uppercase if not
  # and remove any non valid symbols
  # Input: symbols = vector of stock tickers
  # Output: filtered_symbols = filtered symbols
  
  # convert symbols to uppercase
  symbols <- toupper(symbols)
  
  # Validate the symbol names
  valid <- regexpr("^[A-Z]{2,4}$", symbols)
  
  # Return only the valid ones
  return(sort(symbols[valid == 1]))
}

# Create the list of stock tickers and check that they are valid symbols
tickers <- filter_and_sort_symbols(c("AAPL", "NVDA", "MLM", "AA"))
benchmark <- "SPY"
# Set the start and end dates
start_date <- "2007-01-01"
end_date <- "2019-01-01"

# Gather the stock data using quantmod library
getSymbols(Symbols=tickers, from=start_date, to=end_date, auto.assign = TRUE)
getSymbols(benchmark, from=start_date, to=end_date, auto.assign = TRUE)

# Create a matrix of only the adj. prices
price_matrix <- NULL
for(ticker in tickers){price_matrix <- cbind(price_matrix, get(ticker)[,6])}
# Set the column names for the price matrix
colnames(price_matrix) <- tickers
benchmark_price_matrix <- NULL
benchmark_price_matrix <- cbind(benchmark_price_matrix, get(benchmark)[,6])

# Compute log returns
returns_matrix <- NULL
for(ticker in tickers){returns_matrix <- cbind(returns_matrix, annualReturn(get(ticker)))}
returns_covar <- cov(returns_matrix)
colnames(returns_covar) <- tickers
rownames(returns_covar) <- tickers
# get average returns for tickers and benchmark
ticker_avg <- NULL
for(ticker in tickers){ticker_avg <- cbind(ticker_avg, colMeans(annualReturn(get(ticker))))}
colnames(ticker_avg) <- tickers
benchmark_avg <- colMeans(annualReturn(get(benchmark)))

# create the objective function
calculate_portfolio_variance <- function(allocations, returns_covar, ticker_avg, benchmark_avg)
{
  # Name: calculate_portfolio_variance
  # Purpose: Computes expected portfolio variance, to be used as the minimization objective function
  # Input: allocations = vector of allocations to be adjusted for optimality; returns_covar = covariance matrix of stock returns
  #        ticker_avg = vector of average returns for all tickers, benchmark_avg = benchmark avg. return
  # Output: Expected portfolio variance
  
  # get benchmark volatility 
  benchmark_variance <- (sd(annualReturn(get(benchmark))))^2
  # scale allocations for 100% investment
  allocations <- as.matrix(allocations/sum(allocations))
  # get the naive allocations
  naive_allocations <- rep(c(1/ncol(ticker_avg)), times=ncol(ticker_avg))
  portfolio_return <-  sum(t(allocations)*ticker_avg)
  portfolio_variance <- t(allocations)%*%returns_covar%*%allocations
  
  # constraints = portfolio expected return must be greater than benchmark avg. return and
  #               portfolio variance must be less than benchmark variance (i.e. a better reward at less risk)
  if(portfolio_return < benchmark_avg | portfolio_variance > benchmark_variance)
  {
    allocations <- naive_allocations
  }
  
  portfolio_variance <- t(allocations)%*%returns_covar%*%allocations
  return(portfolio_variance)
}


# Specify lower and upper bounds for the allocation percentages
lower <- rep(0, ncol(returns_matrix))
upper <- rep(1, ncol(returns_matrix))

# Initialize the allocations by evenly distributing among all tickers
set.seed(1234)
allocations <- rep(1/length(tickers), times=length(tickers))
```

When I call the objective function manually, it returns a value as expected:

```
> calculate_portfolio_variance(allocations, returns_covar, ticker_avg, benchmark_avg)
          [,1]
[1,] 0.1713439
```

However, when I use the `optim()` function it returns the error:

```
> optim_result <- optim(par=allocations, fn=calculate_portfolio_variance(allocations, ticker_avg, benchmark_avg), lower=lower, upper=upper, method="L-BFGS-B")
Error in t(allocations) %*% returns_covar : non-conformable arguments
```

I'm not sure the reason, but it may be with the way `optim()` recursively uses the `allocations` variable. What can I do to fix this?

Edit: FWIW, other optimization strategies work (differential evolution, simulated annealing) but I would prefer to use gradient descent because it is considerably faster

Comment: It's very clearly telling you that the column count of `t(allocations)` and  and the row count of `returns_covar` are not equal. What you should do is check for this and return an informative error message so any further users of this function will benefit from your foresight. Also `fn=calculate_portfolio_variance(allocations, ticker_avg, benchmark_avg)` is not a function, it is a call.

Comment: @IRTFM I understand the error; the reason I detailed the manual call in the question was because it does not cause this error. Hence my leading question about why the dimensions potentially change when recursively using allocations in the optim function. I originally used `optim_result <- optim(par=allocations, fn=calculate_portfolio_variance, lower=lower, upper=upper, allocations=allocations, ticker_avg=ticker_avg, benchmark_avg=benchmark_avg, method="L-BFGS-B")` but this causes the same error without additional details

Comment: The errors might have been the same but the causes of the errors were different. In the first instance you were multiplying a 4x1 matrix by a 4x1 matrix and the cols(1)-rows(2) were not equal; in the second instance from your comment you were multiplying a 4x1 matrix by a NULL object because there was no default value for `returns_covar` in the function parameters construction. You should put a debugging line inside that function that prints the dimensions of the objects just before the line that throws the error.

Comment: You should also do some testing of your function. At the moment it returns exactly the same value for any value of `allocations`, so there would be nothing to optimize even if it didn't throw errors.

Comment: @IRTFM, Ah, yep, you're right I forgot the `returns_covar` argument. Thank you for catching that. However, I don't think the function is the issue; it optimizes fine with other non-gradient methods and I've confirmed the results against the gradient optimizer in Excel.

Comment: When I run your function with a variety of allocations I always get the same value. I'm not sure what that should produce in other optimization schemes but it doesn't seem like a very fruitful starting point to me.

Comment: @IRTFM an equally weighted vector is potentially a valid outcome in the scenario. The `if` statement within the objective function is a means of introducing specified constraints; if the constraints aren't met, the default is to equally weight the allocation. This isn't to say the `optim` function is working as intended; as I edited in the post, the outcome isn't aligning with other optimization methods

Comment: If you give an optimization routine a function whose output is constant, the proper return should be a message that says optimization is not possible. I don't know if `optim` will do that but in any case you have not convinced me that the functions you offered to those other procedure were the same as this one.

Comment: @IRTFM It's not the case that the optimization is not possible, it may the case the function cannot find an improvement over the default condition with the specified constraints. I.e., "not feasible" and "no improvement" would be different. Using the `DEoptim` package and the `GenSA` package both use the exact same `calculate_portfolio_variance` function and provide an optimized result. SO suggests giving the minimal amount of code to reproduce the error which I've done and not cluttered the question with additional optimization routines

Comment: I've looked at the help docs for DEoptim and GenSA and can find no mention of a portfolio variance function. I've pointed out a couple of errors. I remain highly skeptical that a function which does not return varying outputs for varying inputs can possibly be correct in this setting.

Comment: @IRTFM I'm not sure how familiar you are with the optimization field, but the variance function is the function created to generate the target value to be maximized/minimized. It is not a pre-built function within the optimization libraries. It is passed as the optimization function in DEOptim and GenSA just as I tried to do without success in optim. As stated, I've already used it with those libraries and confirmed the result with an external tool. The only reason I would like to use optim is because it is computationally faster

Comment: We seem to be talking past each other. I ran your function with allocation inputs of `c(0.1,.1,.1,.7)`, `c(0.01,.01,.01,.97)`,, `c(.7,.1,.1,.1)`,  `c(.25,.25,.25,.25)`, `c(.1, .1, .1, .9)` and each and every time I get the same result: 0.1713439. So it doesn't vary in its output for extreme variation in input allocations and it also doesn't give a warning message for compositions that do not sum to 1. Failure to throw an error is NOT a test of correctness. Returning a value is likewise NOT a test of correctness.

Comment: @IRTFM that is working as intended. It is returning the variance of the naive allocation, I.e., the evenly-weighted allocation, because the allocation you provided does improve upon the default within the constraints. Note the if statement in the function that sets the default condition when the specified constraints are not met. This isn’t ideal, but is an imposed workaround because the BGFS algorithm is a non-constrained gradient descent algorithm

Comment: I suspect the reset to naive allocations is why it works with the other methods but not gradient descent. DE for example has some inherent randomness while gradient methods may not under all setups

Comment: In what way does it "work". What result do you get that improves upon the "naive allocations? I didn't find any such with `res <- numeric(1000); for( i in 1:1000){ alloc <- runif(4); alloc <- alloc/sum(alloc); res[i] <- calculate_portfolio_variance(alloc, returns_covar, ticker_avg, benchmark_avg) }`. You code doesn't seem to capture the stochastic nature of portfolio returns. You are just using one realization of prices when you should be examining many alternative series.

Comment: @IRTFM in this toy example it will be difficult to improve upon the naive strategy, mainly because the stocks shown are tech/cyclical which tend to be much more volatile than a diversified benchmark like the S&P 500. Mating the appropriate stocks to a particular benchmark is part of the larger strategy. If you select a list of more diversified stocks to mate with a diversified benchmark it works fine with the other optimization strategies. The "one realization" is because this just one period, the larger strategy rebalances many times over a backtest period to accommodate variance in returns

Comment: @IRTFM the search space is too large (even with four stocks) to expect a randomly selected stock allocation to improve upon an evenly balanced strategy. Literature shows many optimization strategies are bested by a simple naive approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No error occurs if the first argument is renamed par and you switch the order in which you apply t() to the parameter vectors used in that flanking matrix-multiply operation:

```
cpv <- function(par, returns_covar=returns_covar, ticker_avg, benchmark_avg)
{
    # Name: calculate_portfolio_variance
    # Purpose: Computes expected portfolio variance, to be used as the minimization objective function
    # Input: allocations = vector of allocations to be adjusted for optimality; returns_covar = covariance matrix of stock returns
    #        ticker_avg = vector of average returns for all tickers, benchmark_avg = benchmark avg. return
    # Output: Expected portfolio variance
    
    # get benchmark volatility 
    benchmark_variance <- (sd(annualReturn(get(benchmark))))^2
    # scale allocations for 100% investment
    par <- as.matrix(par/sum(par))
    # get the naive allocations
    naive_allocations <- rep(c(1/ncol(ticker_avg)), times=ncol(ticker_avg))
    portfolio_return <-  sum(t(par)*ticker_avg);print(par)
    portfolio_variance <- t(par)%*%returns_covar%*%par
    
    # constraints = portfolio expected return must be greater than benchmark avg. return and
    #               portfolio variance must be less than benchmark variance (i.e. a better reward at less risk)
    if(portfolio_return < benchmark_avg | portfolio_variance > benchmark_variance)
    {
        par <- naive_allocations
    }
    
    portfolio_variance <- t(par)%*%returns_covar%*%par
    return(portfolio_variance)
}
```

I left the debugging printing of par in the code and show the top of the results of running it

```
optim_result <- optim(par=allocations, fn=cpv, lower=lower, upper=upper, returns_covar=returns_covar, ticker_avg=ticker_avg, benchmark_avg=benchmark_avg, method="L-BFGS-B")
     [,1]
[1,] 0.25
[2,] 0.25
[3,] 0.25
[4,] 0.25
          [,1]
[1,] 0.2507493
[2,] 0.2497502
[3,] 0.2497502
[4,] 0.2497502
          [,1]
[1,] 0.2492492
[2,] 0.2502503
[3,] 0.2502503
[4,] 0.2502503
#--- snipped output of six more iterations.
```

... and the result:

```
> optim_result 
$par
[1] 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25

$value
[1] 0.1713439

$counts
function gradient 
       1        1 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: NORM OF PROJECTED GRADIENT <= PGTOL"
```

As I said in the comment to an unrelated question, the optim function first tried to raise then lower the first element in par, then tries to do the same for the second, third and fourth elements. At that point finding no improvement it "decides" it's converged at a local minimum and declares convergence.

I should point out that the code for `optim` is [rather old and the author of the original algorithm, Dr Nash](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2020/RJ-2020-029/RJ-2020-029.pdf), has placed an updated version on CRAN in the form of [the  `optimx` package](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/287763453_On_Best_Practice_Optimization_Methods_in_R/fulltext/56957da108ae3ad8e33d7092/On-Best-Practice-Optimization-Methods-in-R.pdf). He says `optim` was good in its day, but that he thinks other procedures should be tried if it's not successful.

Comment: Thank you. Out of curiosity, is there a reason you hardcoded `returns_covar=returns_covar` in this way in the `cpv` function arguments? You've answered the original question just fine, but I will have to see if gradient descent will work or is prone to getting stuck in a local minima.

Comment: I'm not sure that  `returns_covar=returns_covar` is needed. Probably would work without the parameter passing with `=`. And `optim` is only going to find local minima. It has never been claimed to search widely to try to find better results in a global search.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understand the drawbacks of gradient methods in not being assured of finding a global minima, but I was hoping it would perform a bit closer the GRG2 algo in Excel. It looks like modifying the step size in `optim` may not be the best idea for helping in this case so I may be better off with other optimization functions that align closer with the results of GRG2

Comment: @coolhand There's always this to consider: http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~bdm25/chap8.pdf . It's the basis for the quote from R-help at:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175869/generalized-reduced-gradient-grg2-algorithm-in-r/37590614#37590614